# WPF TabControl and DataGrid Combobox Columns return to initial position after Tab Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've a strange problem, and hope someone can help me with my struggle.
Here is the problem.
I have an application that needs to create dynamically `TabItem`'s in one main `TabControl`.
The main window has two buttons in a `StackPanel`, and one `TabControl` (that will host the different `TabItem` instances:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Content="Tab1" Command="{Binding AddTab}" CommandParameter="Tab1"/>
        <Button Content="Tab2" Command="{Binding AddTab}" CommandParameter="Tab2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTabItem}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemItemTemplate}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

In the CodeBehind of the main window, a set the `DataContext` to a new class that has public property for all opened `TabItem` instances, for the selected Tab, and a command for adding a new tab:

```
    public ICommand AddTab { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems { get; set; }
    private TabItem _currentTabItem;
    public TabItem CurrentTabItem 
               {
                 get {return _currentTabItem;} 
                 set
                     {
                       if(_currentTabItem == value) return;
                        _currentTabItem = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameOf(CurrentTabItem);
                      }
               }
```

And a function that handles adding the new tab:

```
private void OnAddTabExecute(object obj)
    {
        var type = obj as string;
        if (type != null)
        {
            TabItem ti;
            if (type == "Tab1")
            {
                ti = new Tab1ViewModel();

            }
            else
            {
                ti = new Tab2ViewModel();
            }
            TabItems.Add(ti);
            CurrentTabItem = ti;
        }
```

In the Main Window I'm declaring two DataTemplates that are responsible to "wire" the selected "Tab1ViewModel" or "Tab2ViewModel" a corresponding View:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tab1ViewModel}">
        <local:Tab1View/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tab2ViewModel}">
        <local:Tab2View/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

So far so good!! Everything works perfect!!! Then in the `local:Tab1View.xaml` I add another TabControl with manually added TabItems:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <TabItem Header="New Tab">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ThisThings}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Countries, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                          SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding CountryID}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Newer Tab">
            <TextBlock Text="This is test tab"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

The presented properties are in the ViewModel, and Everything loads up as I wanted, BUT here is the problem:

[image: This is how it looks]

1. I push the Tab2 button and Tab2 shows up (no problems)
   2.I push the Tab1 button and Tab1 loads up, with all selected data in the comboboxes:

[image: This is how it looks]

Notice the selected countries: "Bulgaria" (row1), "UK" (row2), "Russia" (row3).
3. Change the "UK" selection from row 2, to "Germany".

[image: This is how it looks]

4. Select from the inner TabControl the "Newer Tab", and get back to the "New Tab". The row 2 selection is still "Germany"

5.Select "Tab 2" tab from the outer TabControl, and get back to "Tab 1", The selection is back from "Germany" to "UK", as it was at the load up of tab.

I red somewhere that when you select a current tab, the one that is unselected is taken out from the Visual tree. But why then it is not happening when I change the inner TabControl's tabs? This drive's me crazy.

I have a solution with the project, if anyone needs it, I can present it. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2VDQypXfZUhZ1NiV21RUzdBa3M?usp=sharing) I hope it works! (When you start the project, the window in the screenshots shows, by clicking on the "Show" button)

I'll appritiate any ideas what is wrong with this, and how it can be fixed

---

EDIT on 01/03/2017
I'm providing the code for the `Tab1ViewModel`:

```
public class Tab1ViewModel : TabItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Thing> ThisThings { get; set; }

    public Thing ThisThing { get; set; }

    //public NewerTabViewModel NewerTabViewModel { get; set; }
    //public NewTabViewModel NewTabViewModel { get; set; }

    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

    public override string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return "Tab 1";
        }
    }

    public Tab1ViewModel()
    {

        ThisThings = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
        ThisThings.Add(new Thing() { CountryID = 1, Name = "Greg" });
        ThisThings.Add(new Thing() { CountryID = 2, Name = "John" });
        ThisThings.Add(new Thing() { CountryID = 4, Name = "Sam" });

        ThisThing = new Thing()
        {
            CountryID = 3,
            Name = "Thingy",
            //HisThings = ThisThings
        };

        //NewTabViewModel = new NewTabViewModel(ThisThing);
        //NewerTabViewModel = new NewerTabViewModel(ThisThing);

        Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        Countries.Add(new Country() { ID = 1, Description = "Bulgaria" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { ID = 2, Description = "UK" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { ID = 3, Description = "USA" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { ID = 4, Description = "Russia" });
        Countries.Add(new Country() { ID = 5, Description = "Germany" });
    }
}
```

Comment: ThisThings is a collection? Could you provide the related source? I suspect your SelectedValue="{Binding CountryID}" binding is not working.

Comment: Hi @DerrickMoeller,
I've just edited the original post with the way I initialize the `ThisThings` collection, and the ThisThing object and the Countries collection

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem: You create a new TabItem every time your select your tab:

**This:**

```
private TabItem _currentTabItem;
public TabItem CurrentTabItem {get;set;}
```

**Should be:**

```
private TabItem _currentTabItem;
public TabItem CurrentTabItem 
                 {
                     get {return _currentTabItem;} 
                     set
                         {
                           if(_currentTabItem == value) return;
                            _currentTabItem = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged(nameOf(CurrentTabItem);
                          }
                   }
```

Comment: Hi @Nawed Nabi Zada,
Nope, this was not the solution. I've tried it, and it not affect the strange behavior. I'll edit the code from the original post, so not to confuse someone else. Thanks for the suggestion tho.